# function of class Y is not a member of X, but class X is a friend of Y

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

There is a similar question to this with the function being an operator overload with arguments and that is the main emphasis, which is only confusing me further.

I am simply trying to execute a short recursive function on a tree class that gets called on non-empty Node objects in order to traverse down the tree's child nodes respectively.

My class declarations are as such:

```
    template<class T>
    class BTNode {
        template<class I>
        friend class BST;
        T data;
        BTNode<T>* left_;
        BTNode<T>* right_;
    ...
    }

template<class I>
class BST {
    BTNode<I>* root_;
    BTNode<I>* curr_;
    BTNode<I>* parent_;
    int currSize = 0;

public:

    size_t size() const {
        if (root_ == NULL) {
            return currSize;
        }
        else {
            BTNode<I>* left_ = root_->getLeft();
            BTNode<I>* right_ = root_->getRight();

            if (left_ != NULL) 
                currSize += left_->size();
            if (right_ != NULL) 
                currSize += right_->size();
        }

        return currSize;
    }
...
};
```

The error as it stands is:

```
'size()': is not a member of 'BTNode<I>'
```

So far, I have tried make BTNode a friend class of BST, and the error still prevails (having both classes become friends of each other).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there actually a function `size()` in `BTNode`? You haven't shown one; is it in the `..` part?

Comment: No, how I understood the friendship was that I can invoke the tree's size() function on Node objects since the tree class is a friend of node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what `friend` declarations do. Saying that `A` is a friend of `B` means that `A` gains access to `protected` and `private` members of `B`. It allows `A` to call `private` functions of `B`, for example. It does not extend the interface of `A` or `B` in any way.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you should be able to do that by having `size` take a parameter:

```
template<class I>
class BST {
    BTNode<I>* root_;
    BTNode<I>* curr_;
    BTNode<I>* parent_;

public:

    size_t size() const {
        return size_(root_);
    }

private:
    static size_t size_(const BTNode<I> *node) {
        if (node == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1 + size_(node->getLeft()) + size_(node->getRight());
        }
    }

...

};
```

Comment: So this can't work without BST being a derived class of Node then?

Comment: @learnenburn I added what I believe is a solution which does not introduce any such inheritance.